# Is calling requestAnimationFrame with Raphael a performance hit?

Tags: javascript, raphael, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a fairly resource hungry web application which heavily relies on Raphael.js for roughly 50% of the animations used, the rest I have rolled my own animation method which uses webkitRequestAnimationFrame in conjunction with the the Web Audio API's context.currentTime to sync animations with the audio component.

I am experiencing pretty terrible performance at the moment and looking through Raphael's source I see that it also uses requestAnimationFrame. Most of the lag I am experiencing seems to occur when both my animations and Raphael's are running concurrently. Is this because requestAnimationFrame is essentially being called twice per draw cycle?

Essentially what I'm asking is basically do I have to re-roll my own implementation of an animate for raphael objects and stick it in with my existing requestAnimationFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm as far as I know the whole point of RAF is to sync everything so that its ready for the next render update. I would be doing exactly the same as you as the this is the whole point of  it.

As per the spec:

> The expectation is that the user agent will run tasks from the animation task source at at a regular interval matching the display's refresh rate. Running tasks at a lower rate can result in animations not appearing smooth. Running tasks at a higher rate can cause extra computation to occur without a user-visible benefit.

So I would say NO it shouldn't be a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with sluggish SVG animation. My understanding of RAF is that it batches updates together wherever they come from, so I dont think that was your problem.

I've found that most of my cycles are taken up by repainting. There's not much you can do JS-wise to speed up repainting. But I think you can make it easier on the browser by cutting down on transparency effects, filters, and large areas of the screen changing. Also, repainting is a function of the the amount of pixels that you're updating. I'm making a full-screen site and when I double the viewport size, it doubles my paint time.